# Populate Additional Fields Based On Select Value WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

So my site has a custom field implemented with a drop down of suburbs , upon clicking how do I make the City and the Post code related to that item.
Example: I select Bat Cave from the drop down, it would populated Post with 0101 and City with Gothem

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');
function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields) {
    $fields['billing_suburb'] = array(
        'label'         => __('Your Suburb', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder'   => _x('Your Suburb', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required'      => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear'         => false, // add clear or not
        'type'          => 'select',
        'options'       => array(
        '' => 'Please select',
                    'ny'    => 'Nester',
```

How do I tie values into those selects so that they can populate the additional fields.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: In/through which hook do you use your added code? where did you put this code? because if I just copy/paste this I get a whole series of errors.. 
So it looks like a piece of code is missing? - Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Code is running well on the site and pulling down into our legacy system using the REST API , hook is now provided. Now the issue is that a selection from here has certain criteria attached like their post codes and their city, that need to populate afterwards.

Comment: There still seems to be a piece of code missing... for example 
the closing bracket in your callback function.. if I understand your question correctly, you want an action to be performed when a certain choice is made via the dropdown menu? 
"post" & "city" is about the default WooCommerce billing fields?

Comment: Hmmm right now all I've built is this form , and it passes those values through my sticking point is exactly as you describe where I want if a user selects one then it will go through an array or object (not sure whats the best approach) and grab the fields related to that such as the city and post and yep the defaults and populate them